# Black Cavalry Fork Attack

Tags: mathematics, chess, optimization

#### On this chess optimization puzzle, there are only black knights and white queens. Your aim is that no black knight is threatened and to maximize the total number of queens the knights could capture. You can use as many knights and queens as you want.

On the following very low example, the score for black knights is 8.

[image]

Comment: Can we use more than 4 black knights?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky yes! You can use as many knights as you want from 1 to 63! Same for white queens

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been trying to beat the benchmark for a couple of days, and I have not been able to. However, I can tie it.

> Also 24
>  [image: Chessboard]
>  ([lichess](https://lichess.org/editor/3Q3Q/1n3n2/2n3n1/Q3Q3/3Q3Q/1n3n2/2n3n1/Q3Q3_w_-_-_0_1))
>
>  Although it was unintentional, all queens here are also in the first answer, and all knights in the first answer are here. I'm going to have to be happy having tied while using an equal number of knights and queens (and 4 fewer pieces).

Answer (score 8):

Just to set a basemark, by extending your example, I can get to

> 24
>  [image]
>  ([link](https://lichess.org/editor/3Q3Q/1n3n2/3Q3Q/Q1Q1Q1Q1/3Q3Q/1n3n2/3Q3Q/Q1Q1Q1Q1_w_-_-_0_1))

Comment: Wanting to set a basemark you equaled my best score, I'm very curious to know if someone's gonna beat it or if someone could prove this is the optimal value

Comment: I've seen a couple users here who are very skilled in integer programming, I'm sure they can find the optimal solution.

Comment: Oh! people solve such problems with integer programming! I didn't think of this idea, but now it's obvious that's a great idea for solving them... I'm even gladder I post my puzzle haha